# How to write a list to a text file exactly as it appears in python?

Tags: python

I want to be able to write a list to a text file, exactly as this would appear if I would just print it out in the console (with the brackets and everything). The reason being, I need to use the list later on and it has to appear just as it normally would if being printed.

I've tried using the csv module, but I couldn't get it formatted like I wanted.

Any suggestions?

Comment: " I need to use the list later on and it has to appear just as it normally would if being printed." => looks like an XY problem. What do you intend to do with this list exactly ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `repr`. repr "returns the canonical string representation of the object", so it should give you the same string that gets printed when you inspect things on the interactive prompt.

```
file.write(repr(my_list))
```

Comment: Or `str`. For a list, they'll do the same thing.

Comment: This is true. The OP should take care for non-list objects, though. Ex. if he wants to write a string to the file, quotes and all, `repr` is preferable to `str`.

Comment: Yeah, for other types it depends exactly what you want. `print` uses `str` if you pass it an arbitrary object, while the REPL of the interactive interpreter uses `repr`.

Comment: @Kevin Thanks so much for your help! Using 'repr' did exactly what I wanted. I'll mark as answered as soon as I am allowed.

Comment: What would I have to do to format it so that each index of the list shows up on a different line?

Comment: I believe the `json` module has some fancy formatting options such as multiple line representation. I don't have a lot of experience with it, though.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a more generic solution, you probably want to use json:

```
import json
my_list = ['hello','world']
print json.dumps(my_list, indent=4, sort_keys=True, separators=(',', ': '))
```

Output is:

```
[
    "hello",
    "world"
]
```

It's useful for more than just lists:

```
my_dict = {
    'hello':1,
    'world':2
}
my_dict['my_list'] = my_list
print json.dumps(my_dict, indent=4, sort_keys=True, separators=(',', ': '))
```

Output is:

```
{
    "hello": 1,
    "my_list": [
        "hello",
        "world"
    ],
    "world": 2
}
```

And the nice part is you can use "json.loads" to change the string back to the original value.  Here is an example where you can save the string to a file, and read it in later to recreate the dictionary:

```
with open(r'c:\my_dict.json', 'w') as f:
    f.write(json.dumps(my_dict, indent=4, sort_keys=True, separators=(',', ': ')))
with open(r'c:\my_dict.json', 'r') as f:
    data = f.read()
    my_loaded_dict = json.loads(data)
print my_loaded_dict['my_list']
print my_loaded_dict.keys()
```

Output is (note that the strings are now unicode):

```
[u'hello', u'world']
[u'world', u'my_list', u'hello']
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make a small helper function to make a string representation of the list

```
def listify(l):
    return '[{}]'.format(', '.join(map(str,l)))

>>> l = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> listify(l)
'[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]'
```

Comment: Oh jeez, I guess I just reinvented the wheel. Time to go get some coffee and not overthink things :)

Answer (score 0):

use str before `write`:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4]
>>> b = str(a)
>>> b
'[1, 2, 3, 4]'
>>> file_descriptor.write(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str` method to wrap in string

```
In [21]: l = [1,2,3]

In [22]: with open("file_test", 'a') as f:
   ....:     f.write(str(l) + "\n")
   ....:     

In [23]:
```